# All spectral projection is trivial implies the operator is identity?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, functional-calculus

We consider $x\in B(H)$ a self-adjoint operator, then we know that it can determine a unique spectral measure $E$. If we know that $E(\Delta)=0$ or $1$ for all measurable $\Delta\subset \sigma(x)$, then it is not hard to show that $x=\lambda I$ for some $\lambda\in \mathbb{R}$.

My question is, if $x$ is not a bounded operator now, it is only a self-adjoint (unbounded) operator, then we know that we can still have a unique spectral measure E. If we know that $E(\Delta)=0$ or $1$ for all measurable $\Delta\subset \sigma(x)$, can we show that $x=\lambda I$ for some $\lambda\in \mathbb{R}$.

Any help will be truly grateful!

Comment: If the spectral measure $E(\lambda)$ of a self-adjoint operator $A$  is trivial so is the spectral measure of its Cayley transform $U.$ Therefore $U=e^{it}I,$ for some  $-\pi<t< \pi.$  This implies $A=(\tan{t\over 2})\, I.$

Comment: Thanks for your help! I think that's true, I get it now!

Comment: $\lambda I$ is a bounded operator. Therefore, you are not going to show that an unbounded $x$ is $\lambda I$.

Comment: My apology, I mean that $x$ may not be a bounded operator now, actually we can show that $x=\lambda I$ by using the comment of Ryszard Szwarc.